# Knockout mapping with JSON

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

```
var data=[
{
id: 25,
message: "4",
messageDateTime: "2013-07-14T20:01:17.46",
userId: 1,
user: {
        id: 1,
        userName: "User A",
        password: "AAA",
        email: "email",
        fullName: "Full Name A"
      }
},
{
id: 24,
message: "3",
messageDateTime: "2013-07-14T20:01:16.42",
userId: 1,
user: {
        id: 1,
        userName: "User A",
        password: "AAA",
        email: "email",
        fullName: "Full Name A"
      }
}]
```

View Model

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
```

VIEW:

```
    <h2 data-bind="text: user.userName"></h2>  
    <p data-bind="text: message"></p>
    <p data-bind="text: messageDateTime"></p>
```

Question: How I can get **userName** in my View. I can get **message** and **messageDateTime** not user data. I think *ko.mapping.fromJS* should mapp my data in to observableArray or am I missing something?

Comment: Your code `data-bind="text: user.userName"` should work just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/RSZgy/

Comment: You are right. I will check my code again. Thanks